# Hide url holder iframe link in adress bar?

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe, get, address-bar

**1.** *Main function*

Ok. First and main function is this:

```
function url( $atts, $content = null ) {
return '<a href="/url/?iframe='.$content.'" target="_blank">'.$content.'</a>';
}
add_shortcode("url", "url");
```

And I use:
    [url]https://stackoverflow.com/[/url]

It returns:

```
<a href="/url/?link=https://stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">https://stackoverflow.com/</a>
```

**2.** *Agreement function*

When is clicked it sends user to agreement to proceed:

```
function url_proceed( $atts, $content = null ) {
$url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url = str_replace('url', 'url.php', $url);
return '<a href="'.$url.'">Proceed</a>';
}
add_shortcode("url_proceed", "url_proceed");
```

This shortcode is placed on page with name and tag: **url**, as function says.

and this would send user to final destination:

```
<a href="/url.php/?iframe=https://stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">Proceed</a>
```

**3.** *Final destination*

**url.php** is in root, with content:

```
<iframe src="<?php echo $_GET['iframe']; ?>" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

**4.** *Address bar*

In address bar in all steps I have `?iframe=https://stackoverflow.com/`

1. http://domain.com/url/?iframe=https://stackoverflow.com/
2. http://domain.com/url.php/?iframe=https://stackoverflow.com/

In address bar I want this `?iframe=https://stackoverflow.com/` to be like this `?iframe=encrypted/obfuscated`, or to remove it but still to be able and used by `$_GET`

Please if someone know solution, I will be thankfull.

I know inspect element will still show source of iframe, but it looks more nice if there is no this holder shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Base64 encode with:

[base64_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)

url:

```
?iframe=aHR0cDovL3N0YWNrb3ZlcmZsb3cuY29tLw==
```

and then decode with:

[base64_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php)

and on the page that receives the parameter you decode

Comment: $content = base64_encode($content); after other changes in first function and variable. $_GET['link'] = base64_decode($_GET['link']); before other changes of variable in last step, and viola, it is working. Working, but still has error:"Uncaught ReferenceError: $iframe is not defined"

Comment: Problem seems to pass the variable to javascript.